# How to make dynamic keybord (not button) with Botman.io framework in Telegram

Tags: php, bots, telegram, botman

How can i make dynamic keybord (not button) with Botman.io framework in Telegram ?
I try this code

```
$arr = array('test1','test2','test3');

        $buttons = array_map(function($name) {
            return KeyboardButton::create($name);
       }, $arr);

$keybord = Keyboard::create(Keyboard::TYPE_KEYBOARD);

$keyboard = call_user_func_array([$keybord, 'addRow'], $buttons);

$this->ask('What is your name',function($answer){
        $this->say('your name is '.$answer->getText());
},$keyboard
```

but i does not working because the $keyboard must end with `toArray()`

can some one help me please